# Swift Delete EventKit Event when List Item is Deleted

Tags: swift, core-data, eventkit

I've built a basic task manager app using the default functionality in Swift when including CoreData in your Xcode project.

From there, I added the ability to include an EventKit event with each task item, which is added when the user calls the addItem() function which lives in a separate view.

The deleteItems() func lives in a separate view which is simply a list of all of the users upcoming tasks.

I'm having trouble adding the `try eventStore.remove(event ?? EKEvent(eventStore: eventStore), span: .futureEvents)` code in the deleteItems() func.

```
private func deleteItems(offsets: IndexSet) {
     withAnimation {
         let incomplete = items.filter {$0.completion == false}
         
         offsets.map { incomplete[$0] }.forEach(viewContext.delete)

         do {
             if self.viewContext.hasChanges {

                try? self.viewContext.save()
             }
         }
     }
 } //: DELETEFUNC
```

All I want to accomplish, is if the task is deleted from the list, the associated event is deleted as well.

---

EDIT:
I was able to add get the .remove operation to work in the delete function by adding a 'for in' code block as below.

I don't really understand why this worked, but it works.. mostly. Now the issue I'm encountering is that the delete function seems to delete any app-generated events in the calendar, not just the specified event.

I feel like it's looping through the events and running the .remove operation multiple times, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Note: if I substitute the `try eventStore.remove(event ?? EKEvent(eventStore: eventStore), span: .futureEvents)` code with a simple `print(event)` it prints just the selected event, and doesn't appear to loop through.

```
private func deleteItems(offsets: IndexSet) {
         withAnimation {
             let incomplete = items.filter {$0.completion == false}

             offsets.map { incomplete[$0] }.forEach(viewContext.delete)

             do {
                 for item in items {
                     if item.timeBoxed {
                        let eventIDReference = item.eventID
                        let event = eventStore.event(withIdentifier: eventIDReference!)
                         
                        try eventStore.remove(event ?? EKEvent(eventStore: eventStore), span: .futureEvents)
                     }
                 }
                 
                 if self.viewContext.hasChanges {
                    try? self.viewContext.save()
                 }
             } catch {
                 print("saving event error: \(error)")
             }
         }
     } //: DELETEFUNC
```

Comment: What does “I'm having trouble adding…” mean?… Compile error? Runtime error? Nothing happens?

Comment: Valid question - my bad. All of the above, depending on what I have tried. When adding the eventStore.remove code to the function, I get a "cannot find 'event' in scope" error. When declaring event as a variable, it can't find the eventIdentifier attribute, and thus doesn't delete the event even though the error is cleared.
-
I have the eventIdentifier saved to may CoreData object, but can't figure out how to retrieve it in the context of the function. The entity.attribute syntax that I use in other places in my app throws errors as it cannot find the entity in scope either.

Comment: I suggest reading [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/eventkit/retrieving_events_and_reminders) which explains how to fetch events, or just google how to find an `EKEvent` using an identifier. Once you've retrieved a specific event, you pass it to the store to delete it.
PS. You should edit your question to add the information from your comment.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I already am able to fetch events using the eventIdentifier which is stored in my core data object, but I can't seem to pass the context to the delete function properly. -- i.e., if I edit or update the event from my app, the event updates correctly, and if I remove the event from the app in another view, I'm able to delete the event without issue. But in this view, the same object.attribute syntax isn't available as the observed object isn't called in this view.

Comment: From what I can tell, the deleteItems() function doesn't see any of the attributes in my core data object, so I guess my question really is how I can pass the correct attribute to the function, so it can read the eventIdentifier and update the correct event.